# Australian Partner (Provisional) visa (subclass 309) time limit to usage?

Tags: visa, immigration, australia

Sometime in the near future we will be applying for [Partner (Provisional) visa (subclass 309)/Partner (Migrant) visa (subclass 100)](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/309-#tab-content-0) for my wife.  Assuming there are no surprises in the process and the 309 visa gets granted, is there restriction/time limit in which the visa must/should be used after it is granted?

I have looked through the site and can't seem to find any indication of it, but I have a vague feeling in the back of my mind that when we looked into it several years ago there was a 2 year timeframe in which you had to make use of the visa.